# Converting date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date format like this .. `2017-06-05T15:51:56.996-07:00` and I need to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a` . I am using the following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSString* finalDateString = [format stringFromDate:date];`
```

But I couldn't get the hours and AM/PM values right. How can I get this?

Comment: What is going wrong in your conversion. when you say you don't get it right for hours and AM/PM what values are you getting?

Comment: I am getting hour:min value as 10:51 instead of 15:51

Comment: Try using HH instead of hh

Comment: This is a timezone issue. The date you are getting as input is in UTC - 7 timezone and you are trying to convert to local timezone and print. So in your formatting is creating the problem.

Comment: You can see the valid inputs on http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

ZZZ e.g. "-0700"

ZZZZ e.g. "GMT-07:00"

But your input is coming as "07:00" Can you change your input string from the server and get the ":" removed from the timezone?

Comment: uisng HH instead of hh is also not working @himanth

Comment: @kapsym - You are right the original issue is a timezone one; and I think your reading of TR35 is valid, it does seem to not allow a colon in the timezone unless preceded by "GMT". That said, it seems some servers do put in the colon as shown in the question. Historical Q/A indicate that `NSDateFormatter` did not deal with this, but now it seems to - as shown by Sakir Sherasiya answer which works fine for parsing time zones with a colon and non-zero minute offsets. Not that this appears to be in the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *dateStringWithTZ = @"2017-06-05T15:51:56.996-07:00";

// Create date object using the timezone from the input string.
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterWithTZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterWithTZ.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
NSDate *dateWithTZ = [dateFormatterWithTZ dateFromString:dateStringWithTZ];

// Cut off the timezone and create date object using GMT timezone.
NSString *dateStringWithoutTZ = [dateStringWithTZ substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 23)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterWithoutTZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterWithoutTZ.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
dateFormatterWithoutTZ.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDate *dateWithoutTZ = [dateFormatterWithoutTZ dateFromString:dateStringWithoutTZ];

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
[format setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
format.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSString* finalDateString = [format stringFromDate:dateWithoutTZ];
```

RESULT: 2017-06-05 03:51 PM

Comment: Sorry, this simply does not work. Change the input time to `@"2017-06-05T15:51:56.996-08:00"` (time zone offset change) and it produces the same final result. Also the second block of code resulting in `dateWithTZ` is not used in determining `finalDateString`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to set Region of calendar as below:

```
-(NSString *)DateToString:(NSString *)getString
{

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:getString];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
    [format setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    NSString* finalDateString = [format stringFromDate:date];
    return finalDateString;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, @Boobalan why is it not working as you expect?

Comment: the above code is working for this format .."2016-11-28T14:57:30.000Z"  and not for this .. "2017-06-05T15:51:56.996-07:00"